# WPF - Don't stretch image but fit it in a container (or MaxHeight)

Tags: wpf, image, crop, stretch

I would like to display an image in WPF in its original size, which can be achieved by setting Stretch="None". However, if the image is bigger than its enclosing element, the image gets cropped, which is undesirable.

I would like the image to be downsized if it doesn't fit, but not stretched when it is smaller than its enclosing element. Is there a way to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the Image control's `StretchDirection` property:

```
<Image Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="DownOnly" ... />
```